# Ubuntu - Postfix package deletion consequences

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

We have postfix package installed by default on our Linux Ubuntu system.

For some reasons, we need to delete it from the system, is there any consequences for that?

Please note that, we hasn't configured this package to be as mail agent before.

Thanks.

Comment: The consequence will that you will no longer be able to send out emails from this system, including emails to local accounts. For example, `cron` errors will no longer be delivered to the account running the job. If this is not a problem then deleting the package is fine.

Comment: If you don't know the impact of the changes then the reasons are not justified.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.